# ASP.net serving PDF files in browser - issue with browser history

Tags: asp.net, content-disposition

I'm using the following code to serve a PDF file to the browser:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
string filename = "somefilename.pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                         "inline; filename=thefile.pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(filename);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

When this code fires, the URL doesn't change - it simply serves the PDF file.

In non-IE browsers, when I hit back, it goes back to the page that fired the action. However, in IE, I go back to the PREVIOUS page (i.e. the login page, not the page that serves the PDF files.

Just wondering what the best way to handle this so that IE users can click their browser's "back" button and getting a predictable response.

Comment: Where are you calling this code - in a button click, page_load, etc?

Comment: This is on a button click (specifically a link button's command)

Comment: When I click the back button, I go 2 pages back. Happens in IE10.

Comment: If you're in the 3.5/4.0 framework, you could try a HistoryManager control.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you have to use a button to redirect to other webform and in load page copy your code to charge the information that u want to show in pdf and obviously too the code to show this like pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try the history in the Scriptmanager control.

[ASP.NET history](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488548%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hm. Tried this, and get an error: System.InvalidOperationException: A history point can only be created during an asynchronous postback. I'm not doing asynchronous postbacks...

Comment: I think what you need to do is something similar to the ScriptManager and how it works - you need to add a hash to the URL, and use that data to rebuild your page state. Coding this by hand is probably going to be a lot more difficult than implementing AJAX. Is that an option for you?